Failed to collect page data for /books/[bookId]/ with Docker compose
I have an next js 15 app with 'output: "export"', so i need to generate static params when i build it.
As a backend I have Django, from which i get those params.
So when i run
docker compose up --build

next js build gives an error.
[+] Building 72.3s (21/23)                                                                               docker:default
 => [backend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 203B                                                                               0.0s
 => [backend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.12.3-slim                                      0.8s
 => [backend internal] load .dockerignore                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [backend 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.12.3-slim@sha256:afc139a0a640942491ec481ad8dda10f2c5b753f5c9693  0.0s
 => [backend internal] load build context                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 3.59kB                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [backend 2/4] COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [backend 3/4] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                                                       0.0s
 => [backend 4/4] COPY . .                                                                                         0.1s
 => [backend] exporting to image                                                                                   0.1s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                            0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:6d0647588ed5ff0f17a12d01f1856970814411e1d0ba14617d7a85955437c671                       0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/sirius-ai-main-backend                                                          0.0s
 => [backend] resolving provenance for metadata file                                                               0.0s
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 316B                                                                               0.0s
 => WARN: FromAsCasing: 'as' and 'FROM' keywords' casing do not match (line 1)                                     0.0s
 => [frontend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:stable-alpine                                    0.0s
 => [frontend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:alpine                                            0.8s
 => [frontend internal] load .dockerignore                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [frontend build 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:alpine@sha256:1467ea23cce893347696b155b9e00e7f0ac7d21555eb6f  0.0s
 => CACHED [frontend stage-1 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:stable-alpine                                       0.0s
 => [frontend internal] load build context                                                                         0.1s
 => => transferring context: 10.74kB                                                                               0.1s
 => CACHED [frontend build 2/5] COPY package.json package.json                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [frontend build 3/5] RUN npm install                                                                    0.0s
 => [frontend build 4/5] COPY . .                                                                                  0.1s
 => ERROR [frontend build 5/5] RUN npm run build                                                                  69.8s
------
 > [frontend build 5/5] RUN npm run build:
0.792
0.792 > frontend_library@0.1.0 build
0.792 > next build
0.792
2.511 Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
2.513 This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
2.513 You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
2.514 https://nextjs.org/telemetry
2.514
2.744    ▲ Next.js 15.0.2
2.746    - Environments: .env
2.746
2.808    Creating an optimized production build ...
24.69 <w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
54.38 <w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
54.97  ✓ Compiled successfully
54.99    Linting and checking validity of types ...
68.09    Collecting page data ...
69.56 TypeError: fetch failed
69.56     at async Object.o [as generateStaticParams] (/.next/server/app/(main)/books/[bookId]/quiz/page.js:1:10399)
69.56     at async builtRouteParams (/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:986:36)
69.56     at async buildAppStaticPaths (/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:940:25)
69.56     at async (/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1149:79)
69.56     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:153:20) {
69.56   [cause]: [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND backend] {
69.56     errno: -3008,
69.56     code: 'ENOTFOUND',
69.56     syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
69.56     hostname: 'backend'
69.56   }
69.56 }
69.56
69.56 > Build error occurred
69.57 Error: Failed to collect page data for /books/[bookId]/quiz
69.57     at <unknown> (/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1233:15) {
69.57   type: 'Error'
69.57 }
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Next js config
import type { NextConfig } from "next";

const nextConfig: NextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: false,
    images: {
        unoptimized: true,
    },
    env: {
        BACKEND_IP_ADDRESS: process.env.BACKEND_IP_ADDRESS,
        LIVE_UPDATE_URL: process.env.LIVE_UPDATE_URL,
    },
    output: 'export',
};
export default nextConfig;

And that's the code that gives an error
import React from "react";

export async function generateStaticParams() {
    const books = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL + "/books/", {
        method: "GET",
    }).then((res) => res.json());

    return books.map((book: { id: { toString: () => any; }; }) => ({
        bookId: book.id.toString(),
    }));
}


interface BookIdPageProps {
    params: Promise<{
        bookId: number;
    }>;
}


async function BookIdPage({params}: BookIdPageProps) {
    const {bookId} = await params;

    return (
        {bookId}
    )

The variable NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL equals to http://backend:8000, while it builds.
That is my docker-compose.yml
networks:
  dev:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
    volumes:
      - './nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
    networks:
      - dev

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend_library
    networks:
      - dev


  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend_library
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - dev

Django dockerfile
FROM python:3.12.3-slim

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python","manage.py","runserver","0.0.0.0:8000"]

Nextjs dockerfile
FROM node:alpine AS build

COPY wait-for-it.sh /wait-for-it.sh

COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x /wait-for-it.sh
RUN apk add --no-cache bash && ls -l /wait-for-it.sh && /wait-for-it.sh backend:8000 -- npm run build

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine

COPY --from=build /out /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]

I tried using wait-for-it.sh but it just loops. Made frontend depend on backend. It gave nothing
Okay now i dont think that is even possible. As i need my django service to be build ans started up by the time my nextjs service starts to build.
But maybe there is a way i could do it?
